# GeoJSON location in UML Class diagram

Tags: json, uml

I have a geoJSON object like the following (according to: http://geojson.org/):

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  }
}
```

I have the following UML class and need to represent this location in class diagram:

[image]

the BusinessLocation attribute will be of type geoJSON location shown in the first snippet. Do I need to have additional structures in the class diagram that clarifies Location i.e. the Location has a type, a geometry with a type, coordinates...etc? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to show the class structure of `Location` and make an association with `Business`:

[image]

- I uses lower case for the owned property `businessLocation`.
- `geometry` and `properties` are structured and should be specified as class structures as well (did not do that here).
- You might stereotype `Location` with `<<JSON>>` or so if you like.